# Oracle - How to know a bulk insert has ended?

Tags: oracle, bulkinsert

We have a table in the Oracle database that act as the intermediary between two systems. System A will do a bulk insert into the table, committing every 50,000 rows. System B will keep querying the table for record, and if there is any, will issue a `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` statement to process the records (System B is multi-threaded).

The issue is, there are chance whereby System A is still bulk inserting the data when System B query the table. This might cause System B to getting incomplete data set for processing.

Is there anyway we can know whether the bulk insert has stopped? If we want to monitor whether there is any `insert` activity done on the table, is it possible? We don't have control on how System A works unfortunately, so we can't have it to send us any 'ending' signal.

Any comments are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You could query the active database sessions to see if System A is still connected.

Comment: If system A is connected to the database but it is doing other things it is fine, the question is whether we can know that it has stopped putting data into the table

Comment: How many records does system B process at a time ???

Comment: U can have a temp table with primary key of your table and processed flag so that you know which rows are processed and the remaining you can process in system B

Comment: You could check for what query SQL system A is currently running.

Comment: Hmm i can get from the `v$sqlarea` view, but the data in this list is removed by using the 'least-used-out' algorithm right? I can determine whether System A has stopped inserting data from it?

Comment: @psaraj12 The processing of System B is ok, the issue is to make sure when system B grabs the data, System A has finished the bulk insert into the table.

Comment: @ipohfly the problem as I see is that when system B is processing data insert might happen in system A so they may not be processed using temp table u can process that data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle will [automatically acquire row/table level locks](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502) when an INSERT is being performed.

If System A provides enough visible information in [`V$SESSION`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_3016.htm#REFRN30223), the system view that shows all connected sessions, in order for you to positively identify only System A's sessions, you should be able to query [`V$LOCKED_OBJECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_2030.htm#REFRN30125) to find objects locked by those sessions:

```
select count(*)
  from v$locked_object v
  join all_objects d
    on v.object_id = d.object_id
  join v$session s
    on v.session_id = s.sid
 where d.owner = :owner
   and d.object_name = :table_name
   and s.<some_identifying_data> = :something
```

If System A is locking your object then you need to continue waiting; if System A *was* locking the object and is no longer then you can start your secondary process. This will require testing to determine the exact behaviour of System A.

I understand that this isn't completely possible, but a more integrated way would be to modify the System A process such that it raised some form of event on termination. You [can use this event to start a scheduled job](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN10020).

Comment: yeah modification on System A wasn't possible, but the idea of using locks  to do this might cut it. I'll give it a look. Thanks =)

Comment: We did a small sample test and it seems to work, basically following your idea to look for locks. Yet to test with a large data set though, but still i think it's good enough to mark this as an answer.